# VS Code doesn't open after changing its location

Tags: visual-studio-code

When i changed the location of VS code from a local file to the desktop, it didn't open. It says it misses the file named "ffmpeg.lll".

I found the file and changed its location too but that's not a solution besides it still didn't open. It then brought up a debug file that says "Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received ."